Add images assets in angular library
I'm in the process of creating an angular library so that I can reuse certain functionalities between 2 projects without having to copy and paste.
I'm faced with a problem: How to add images for use in an Angular library? I have to admit that the documentation isn't very clear on this subject and it hasn't really helped me. I've skimmed and read several articles but nothing that could help me.
Here's what I've been trying to do that hasn't worked so far
I've configured the ng-package.json file to add my assets folder to its build
ng-package.json file
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/blog-editor",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": [
      "./src/styles"
    ]
  },
  "assets": [
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "src/assets",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ]
}

source folder

build folder

And here's how I try to use this image in my code
  <div style="position: relative; aspect-ratio: 16/9; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(203 213 225);">
    <img [ngSrc]="ctrl.value || './assets/images/default-cover.svg'" alt="cover image" style="object-fit: cover" fill
         priority>
  </div>

Here's the error I get when I run my library on the host application

PS:

my project is under Angular 17
the command I use to build my project ng build blog-editor --watch --configuration development
how to launch the host app to test my library locally ng serve --project blog-editor-playground


This is expected, you are missing the step to add the files to your application's assets. Angular does not "magically" add all assets from any library, for good reasons. To copy the assets, add the following to your angular.json of your application:
{
  "projects": {
    "your-application-project-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          // ... other build configuration
          "options": {
            // ... other build options
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/your-lib/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

See the application asset configuration docs.

When I do this, I get an error when I launch the project. here's the error "Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(assets)."
I think "assets" property is not allowed in a library project right ?

@SteevenDelucis you need to add this to the configuration of each application, updated my answer. It is not possible to configure this on library level.

So, if i understand, when someone install my app, he have to do this ?

Yes, AFAIK there is no other way.

Thank you. But for this to work I need to install the package so that it's in the node_modules folder, right? But at the moment, I haven't installed my package (so it's not in the node_modules folder) and I'm able to interact with it by importing it directly (I confess I don't really know how it works). So how do I test all this locally?

Correct, you need to build the library and install it in your application. To test it locally, you can run npm install ../relative-path-to-library/dist/library-name. Or run npm pack on the library build output  and install the package via the generated .tgz file.

Thanks you very munch. One last question. Why hasn't Angular included an asset manager for libraries? Even for global styles? There's nothing about it
